# Inserting text into the filtext box of the devexpress grid

Tags: gridview, filter, devexpress

i have a devexpress grid being used in web application with asp.net & c#.net? the grid has filter text box for each column .the problem is that i just want to inject a text in to all filtertext box of the devexpress grid columns when the grid is loaded for the first time?

how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
ASPxGridView1.AutoFilterByColumn(ASPxGridView1.Columns["yourColumnName"], "%searchValue");
ASPxGridView1.SettingsText.Title = ASPxGridView1.FilterExpression;
```